# .CurrentRegions.Rows.Count inserts data from UserForm textboxes to 900th+ row in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I had this code working before but I seem to have a problem with it today, it inserts data from my UserForm textboxes to the 900th+ row in the sheet. Why is this?

```
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("ERF Logs").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("ERF Logs").Range("A2")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = TextBox8.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = TextBox1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 3) = TextBox6.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4) = TextBox3.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5) = TextBox4.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 6) = TextBox5.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 7) = TextBox7.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 8).Select

End With
```

Comment: `CurrentRegion` is not a reliable method to figure out where your last row of data is - it's also affected by things like formatting.

Comment: I also have this one: Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ERF Logs")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = TextBox8.Value but still does insert the data to the 500th+ row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test2paste()

Dim lr As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ERF Logs")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(lr, 1).Value = TextBox8.Value
    .Cells(lr, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(lr, 3).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(lr, 4).Value = TextBox6.Value
    .Cells(lr, 5).Value = TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(lr, 6).Value = TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(lr, 7).Value = TextBox5.Value
    .Cells(lr, 8).Value = TextBox7.Value
    'And don't use .Select, there are other ways for what you try to achieve I'm sure.
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I did the select because another form shows up where I'll browse a file and after confirming its directory, it inserts the hyperlink to the next cell adjacent to the  
    .Cells(lr, 8).Value

Comment: I just tried your code. Still no luck, it inserts data to the 982nd row. :(

Comment: @LunarRave Have you checked if there are any values in these rows? Like spaces or other chars unseen? If possible, select all rows below the last used row and delete them. And about the .Select, you don't need/should use that. Either browse/confirm a directory before you start populating cells or follow the same path as I did above using lr.

Comment: Pretty sure nothing is in these rows but why does it inserts to the 980-ish rows?

Comment: Update: Apparently my cells were not 'really' blank after all. After Doing Ctrl + - and testing the code, it eventually gone right again. Thanks!